# Eliminate the parameter to find a Cartesian equation of the curve

Tags: calculus, parametric

I've done every problem on this subject except I can't get this one. (every other problem had x = something and y = something.

$$y = (t+1)^{1/2},\quad  y = (t-1)^{1/2}$$

Comment: Are you certain it's two equations for $y$? They each give different values for the same $t$, so they're not consistent.

Comment: I think it's a mistake in the book. Every other question had an x

Comment: I'd tend to agree, especially since if one of them is $x$ then this is just a hyperbola.

Comment: I formatted the equation, but left the typo in there, since the answer referred to it. See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 0):

$y=\sqrt{t+1},y=\sqrt{t-1}$ should be either of the followings :

If you mean $$x=\sqrt{t+1},\ \ y=\sqrt{t-1},$$
then we have
$$x^2=t+1,y^2=t-1\Rightarrow x^2-y^2=(t+1)-(t-1)=2.$$

If you mean $$y=\sqrt{t+1},\ \ x=\sqrt{t-1},$$
then we have
$$y^2=t+1,x^2=t-1\Rightarrow x^2-y^2=(t-1)-(t+1)=-2.$$

Comment: it must be the first one cause y^2 cannot be -2.

Comment: my equation ended up being: y = ((x^2)-2)^1/2

Comment: @user174192: Where does $y^2=-2$ come from? What I wrote is $x^2-y^2=-2$ for the second.

Comment: Oh nevermind i misread

Comment: @user174192: $y=\sqrt{x^2-2}$ can be got from $x^2-y^2=2$. So, we know that the first one in my answer is correct.

Comment: @user174192: You are welcome.